# How to add class to element on canvas?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, css, class, canvas

I would like to add a class in my FirstImg in my code so I can modify it in my CSS but it's not working :

```
    onImageFetch = () =>
    {
        const   imageFirst = 'myfirstimg.jpg';
        const   imgSecond = 'mysecondimg.jpg';
        const   canvas = this.canvas;
        const   img = new Image();
        const   secondImg = new Image();

        img.height = 400;
        img.width = 400;
        img.padding = 10;
        img.classList.add('image-canvas'); // Here I want to add my class
        secondImg.padding = 10;
        img.onload = () =>
        {
            let     ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            const       width = img.width;
            const       height = img.height;

            ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
            ctx.drawImage(secondImg, 260, 30, 70, 25);
        };
        img.src = imageFirst;
        secondImg.src = imgSecond;
    }
```

and my CSS will be something like this :

```
.myNewClassCreate {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
}
```

I tried img.className = 'myclass'; and img.class = 'myclass'; but it's not working.
Need some help, thanks you !

Comment: Your code adds a class to the image just fine (on any vaguely modern browser). But CSS has no effect whatsoever on how an image is rendered when you draw it on a canvas, only when you put the element in a document.

Comment: Thanks for you answer !
So is it possible to add a height/width in percent and to add the property objectif-fit: cover to the img or not ? :/

Comment: [MDN's page on `drawImage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage) certainly suggests scaling is part of the `drawImage` function, yes. But I don't think it's in percentage, you'd have to wait for the image to load and then do the math yourself.